# getting undefined after trying to find on an element generated by template

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have the following code in one of my render function:

```
$newItemView = this.template( {item:this.model} );
$newItemView.find('.other-items-from-same-shop');
```

why is it that I am always getting an undefined when calling find on newItemView? newItemView is there.

My template can be seen [here](http://pastie.org/9264752), When I try to print out $newItemView it prints out the generated html from the template.

Comment: This really needs some more info. Like the template you are using.

Comment: @Baszz what info do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using jQuery so try this:

```
$newItemView = $(this.template( {item:this.model} ));
$newItemView.find('.other-items-from-same-shop');
```